# How to run a python script displaying the command prompt only during user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pywin32

I have a ***python script*** which has a **user input** `val = input("Enter a name ?")` 
I need to ***execute it hiding the command prompt*** and ***displaying it at the time of user input*** and again ***hiding it after user input***. ***How to acheive it using python***?. I tried renaming it to .pyw but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you mean hide window which display `"Enter a name ?"` ? Probably you will need access system functions because you can't control this window. Why don't you use some GUI framework (like `Tkinter`) instead of using `input()` ? And then you can control GUI window.

Comment: Exactly, i need to control the window or Command Prompt

Answer (score 1):

This will hide your console. Implement these lines in your code first to start hiding your console at first.

```
import win32gui, win32con

the_program_to_hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide , win32con.SW_HIDE)
```

If you've got trouble on pip install win32con on Command Prompt, you can simply pip install pywin32.Then on your python script, execute import win32.lib.win32con as win32con instead of import win32con.

To show back your program again win32con.SW_SHOW works fine:

```
win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide , win32con.SW_SHOW)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyboard module to check weather the user has pressed any key and display your input:

```
pip install keyboard
```

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
        if any(keyboard.is_pressed(x) for x in letters):  # if any key is pressed
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        print("other key")
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

You will need an additional thread however if you want to do the processing while you wait for the input.

You can also use system calls to clear the screen in the end:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Comment: It is not just displaying the input, I am intending to hide the command prompt initially. So the command window would be running in the background. Now when the execution reaches input statement, I need to display the command prompt. I need a mechanism to achieve this and then hide the command prompt after the input is received. Basically I need to interact with the properties of command prompt using python code.

Comment: I have added one more answer about how to hide and display the command window. Maybe it helps.